# The issue of CocoaAsyncSocket not being able to successfully pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I just took over a new project, but during the pod process, other frameworks were able to successfully pod, except for CocoaAsyncSocket, which failed due to Failure when receiving data from the peer. Can you give me some advice on what to do.

I have tried to redo the entire project, but there has still been no good result. I have also tried to find people in the community who have the same experience as me, but in the end, there is still no result. I hope someone can give me some help.

Here is my error description：

> [!] Error installing MQTTClient
> [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/novastone-media/MQTT-Client-Framework.git /var/folders/9s/vh78pn9x3bj8xbj4pk173r000000gn/T/d20230919-2306-mbddlw --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.15.2

Cloning into '/var/folders/9s/vh78pn9x3bj8xbj4pk173r000000gn/T/d20230919-2306-mbddlw'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/novastone-media/MQTT-Client-Framework.git/': Recv failure: Operation timed out